# EPPlus Excel report with DateTime before 1900.01.00

Tags: excel, datetime, epplus

I want to create an Excel report with the help of EPPlus but when it puts a date before 1900.01.00. into the Excel worksheet it convers to a negative number or a long '#####...' line appears in the place of a date in the Excel. 
I have set the format but it didn't help:

```
workSheet.Column(columnIndex).Style.Numberformat.Format = "yyyy.mm.dd.";
```

I used this page:

> http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/export-to-excel-in-asp-net-mvc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Excel does not recognize dates before 1900. The date number format is useless. You need to format the date in C# and place the value as string, not as number.

In order to set the number format as text use:

```
workSheet.Column(columnIndex).Style.Numberformat.Format = "@";
```

In order to format the date use the following code, if the date is a datetime:

```
System.IFormatProvider formatProvider = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", true);//or a different culture
dateTime.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd.", formatProvider))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I've done it with this line: dataTable.Columns.Add(ColumnsToTake.ElementAt(i).Value, (property.PropertyType == typeof(System.DateTime) ? typeof(System.String) : (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType) ?? property.PropertyType)));
but I need not the time part of the date and I cannot remove it. Can you help me in it, pls?

Comment: Does it mean I have to go through all cells of the datetime column and format its value into "yyyy.MM.dd." format?

Comment: You can go through all datetimes, if that is easier for you. Or check if the date is before 1900 and format as text and leave the rest the way that are now.

Comment: The code from the comment check only is it is a datetime, but a datetime can be before 1900 and in MS Excel a date cannot exists before 1900.